# Redirect Old Custom Post Type Blog index to main Blog Index

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, blogs

I used to have a Wordpress custom post type, actually had a few, that were 'accidentally' deleted during some recent server problems.

Each one (custom post type) only had a number of posts attributed to it, so I decided not to go through the bother of recreating them and repopulating them, but instead decide to just try and 'forward' any of these URL requests to my main blog, **imjustcreative.com/blog/**

Obviously I'm seeing some 404's being generated as these posts did get indexed, and they are being requested on time-to-time. So I'm simply trying to tidy up these loose ends.

What would be the most efficient way to ensure that any URL request that starts with: **imjustcreative/linkedlist/** but does contain the actual post string after, of which there are a few, for example: **imjustcreative/linkedlist/awesome-post** can be redirected back to a the single blog index url, instead of popping up a 404.

So if I'm seeing:  http://imjustcreative.com/linkedlist/blah-blah and http://imjustcreative.com/linkedlist/blahblachnom coming up as 404's, rather than creating individual post redirects imjustcreative.com/blog/ is there a way to simply state that any thing includes with imjustcreative.com/linkedlist/ and regardless of what post title comes after is picked up by a single redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this rule in your htaccess (which should be in document root folder in this case) right after `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteRule ^/?linkedlist/ /blog/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Wow, OK, that sorted that out. When I think I know a little bit about htaccess, I realise I simply no nothing. :)

Thank you,
G